# How to put seed data into SQL Server docker image?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I have a project using ASP.NET Core and SQL Server. I am trying to put everything in docker containers. For my app I need to have some initial data in the database. 
I am able to use docker sql server image from microsoft (microsoft/mssql-server-linux), but it is (obviously) empty. Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
    web:
        build: .\MyProject
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: "microsoft/mssql-server-linux"
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "your_password1!"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
```

I have an SQL script file that I need to run on the database to insert initial data. I found an [example](https://gist.github.com/jschwarty/6f9907e2871d1ece5bde53d259c18d5f) for mongodb, but I cannot find which tool can I use instead of mongoimport.

Comment: It seems there is are a few images with sql tools, including sqlcmd (for example: ericskang/sqltools), but I couldn't get the complete solution...

Comment: Doesn't the microsoft/mssql-server-linux image already contain SQLCMD at /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd ?

Comment: I don't see any way to do this currently, but there is some discussion [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/229).  You may be able to hack around it by launching sql server in the background, then sleeping, then running a script, as per that [demo repo](https://github.com/twright-msft/mssql-node-docker-demo-app/).  But yuck.

Comment: The tools require a running SQL server which is not the case at build time.

Comment: I ended up doing it from C# code, which is run later in my pipeline.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this by building a custom image. I'm currently using the following solution. Somewhere in your dockerfile should be:

```
RUN mkdir -p /opt/scripts
COPY database.sql /opt/scripts

ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Passw@rd
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y

RUN /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & sleep 30  & /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'Passw@rd' -d master -i /opt/scripts/database.sql
```

Alternatively you can wait for a certain text to be outputted, useful when working on the dockerfile setup, as it is immediate. It's less robust as it relies on some 'random' text of course:

```
RUN ( /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr --accept-eula & ) | grep -q "Service Broker manager has started" \
    && /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'Passw@rd' -i /opt/scripts/database.sql
```

Don't forget to put a database.sql (with your script) next to the dockerfile, as that is copied into the image.

Answer (score 1):

Roet's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52280924/10446284 ditn't work for me.
The trouble was with bash ampersands firing the `sqlcmd` too early. Not waiting for `sleep 30` to finish.

Our Dockerfile now looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-GA

RUN mkdir -p /opt/scripts
COPY db-seed/seed.sql /opt/scripts/

ENV MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Passw@rd
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=true

RUN /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr & sleep 60; /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P 'Passw@rd' -d master -i /opt/scripts/seed.sql
```

Footnotes:

- Now the bash command works like this

  ```
    run-asych(sqlservr) & run-asynch(wait-and-run-sqlcmd)`
  ```
- We chose `sleep 60`, because the build of the docker image happens "offline", before all the runtine evironment is set up. Those 60 seconds don't occur at container runtime anymore. Giving more time for the `sqlservr` command gives our teammates' machines more time to complete the `docker build` phase successfully.

Answer (score 0):

One simple option is to just navigate to the container file system and copy the database files in, and then use a script to attach.

Answer (score 0):

This

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker

has an example of using `sqlcmd` in a docker container although I'm not sure how you would add this to whatever build process you have