# Mount seeded volume on linux host

Tags: linux, docker, docker-volume

I'd like to create a Database image and seed it with some initial data. This seems to work fine, since I'm able to create a container with a volume managed by docker. However, when I try to mount the volume to a directory on my linux host machine, it is created *empty* instead of *seeded*.

After several hours of trying different configurations, I narrowed down the problem to it's core: the content of the folder in the container associated with the volume on the host machine is overwritten upon creation.

Below a simple `Dockerfile` that creates a folder containing a single file. When the container is started it prints out the content of the mounted folder.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN mkdir /opt/test
RUN touch /opt/test/myFile.txt

VOLUME /opt/test

CMD ["ls", "/opt/test"]
```

I'm building the image with: `docker build -t test  .`

**Volume managed by docker**

```
$ docker run -v volume-test:/opt/test --name test test
myFile.txt
```

Here I'm getting the expected output. With the volume mounted in the space managed by docker. So the ouput of `docker volume inspect volume-test` is:

```
{
  "CreatedAt": "2020-05-13T10:09:29+02:00",
  "Driver": "local",
  "Labels": null,
  "Mountpoint": "/var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/volumes/volume-test/_data",
  "Name": "volume-test",
  "Options": null,
  "Scope": "local"
}
```

**Volume mounted on host machine**

```
$ docker run -v $(pwd)/volume:/opt/test --name test test
```

Where nothing is returned since the folder is empty... However, I can see that the volume is created and it's owned by the user root, even though I'm executing the docker run command as another user.

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root    4096 May 13 10:11 volume
```

As a last test, I tried to see what happens when I create the folder for the volume beforehand and add some content to it (in my case a file called `anotherFile.txt`).
When I'm running now the container, I'm getting the following result:

```
$ docker run -v $(pwd)/volume:/opt/test --name test test
anotherFile.txt
```

Which let's me come to the conclusion, that the content in the folder of the container is overwritten by the content of the folder on the host machine.

I can verify as well with `docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' test`, that the volume is mounted at the right place:

```
[{bind  /pathWhere/pwd/pointedTo/volume /opt/test   true rprivate}]
```

**Now my question**: Is there a way to have the same behavior for volumes on the host machine as for the volumes managed by docker, where the content of the /opt/test folder in the container is copied into the folder on the host defined as volume?

---

Sidenote: this seems to be the case when using docker on windows and having the option [Shared Folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/wael-kdouh/enabling-drive-sharing-with-docker-for-windows) enabled...

Furthermore, it seems as a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43346605/docker-on-linux-empty-mounted-volumes) was already asked here but no answer was found. I decided to make a separate post since I think this is the most generic example to describe this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Desired situation**

Data from within the docker image is placed in a specified path on the host.

**Your current situation**

1. When creating the image, data is put into `/opt/test`
2. When starting the container, you mount the volume on `/opt/test`

**Problem**

Because you mount on the same path as where you have put your data, your data gets overwritten.

**Solution**

1. Create a file within image during docker-build, for example `touch /opt/test/data/myFile.txt`,
2. Use a different path to mount your volume, so that the data is not overwritten, for example `/opt/test/mount`
3. Use 'CMD' to copy the files to the volume, like so: CMD ["cp", "-n" "/opt/test/data/*", "/opt/test/mount/"]

**Consulted sources**

- https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/
- https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the provided sources. As the final purpose of my image is to provide a seeded database by following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52280924/6691953), I will have to take a closer look at the risks that might come with copying the whole configuration into the container (and what _"the whole configuration"_ even means...).
However, what's bothering me actually is why I'm able to mount the folder with it's content when I'm just specifing a volume name instead of an absolute path. Do you have any guesses what is causing this behavior?

Comment: @Uchendu, My guess is that if you would put a 'volume name' where a 'path' should be, the command will think that the 'volume name' is a relative path. I wonder what the mount output of ```docker inspect test``` looks like, that could shine some more light on the situation perhaps. I find it difficult to grasp the full context of your situation. :)

Comment: I added the mount output to to my post. Let me know what kind of other information could help to present my situation more precise :)

Comment: @Uchendu, Alright, I hope I'm understanding your question correctly. You want to know why you are able to mount the directory with its contents when specifying a volume name. 
What I think, is that you create this directory ```/opt/test``` when creating the image, so when you look inside the running container you are not looking at a mounted volume 'volume-test'. How about running: ```docker run --name test test``` Do you see the same behaviour then?

Comment: @estherwin, You understand my question correctly. And I think as well the conclusion about the 'volume-test' that is managed my docker and not mounted to a relative path is right.
When running the container without specifying the location for the volume, it creates an 'anonyme' volume. Here the result of looking at the mount part of the container:
`[{volume 9de8d67049480a7e404d9a10dd5f75cfa6cce520aad7720083fa6604bd588d92 /var/snap/docker/common/var-lib-docker/volumes/9de8d67049480a7e404d9a10dd5f75cfa6cce520aad7720083fa6604bd588d92/_data /opt/test local  true }]`

Comment: @Uchendu, and I expect the 'anonymous' volume contains the files, yes? Is there anything else you need clarification for?

Comment: @esthewn No, the source of the problem is clear. But I'm still missing a solution to get the same behavior when specifying the volume on a relative/absolute path. So basically, I'd like to copy the data from within the image onto the host. But as by my comprehension this seems not possible

Comment: @Uchendu, That seems very roundabout to me! But I guess you could do the following: 1. create a file within image during docker-build (like you do already), 2. mount a volume in which you do not override the files (so different path), 3. use 'CMD' to copy the files to the volume, like so: ```CMD ["cp", "/opt/test/myFile.txt", "/mnt/hostsystem/."]```
However, I am very unsure why you would want to do such a thing so please elaborate on your use case if you would like me to think of a better solution.

Comment: @esthewn, That seems to do the trick. But I'm passing the `--no-clubber` arg to the `cp` command as well. I'd gladly accept your answer if you add this approach to your answer.

Comment: @Uchendu, ok, glad I could help. :)